# Can a pothole damage the brakes?

Tags: brakes, wheels

I went over a small pothole near roadworks and there was a quick rattle after I went through it. It didn't felt like a big one, it was almost like mounting the kerb and I was going with less than 30 mph. Soon after hitting it, I noticed the brake pedal has to go deeper than normal to slow down and there was an audible squeak from the brakes.

Just last week, I had my front disks and pads replaced and my rear shoes, drums and cylinders. It could be just the brakes adjusting to the new parts but I somehow suspect the pothole has something to do with it.

Other than that, the car runs fine and the brakes work, although the front ones are hotter than usual. There's also no evident damage on the suspension.

I'm taking the car to the garage tomorrow but I'm wondering if I should expect any damage due to the pothole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the excess travel has only happened once on first application of brakes following the impact etc it maybe just that the caliper piston has retracted slightly. What can happen is that if the brake calipers are shaken violently as in your case by hitting a hole.. The caliper pistons can be forced back into their housings a bit,  this can lead to requiring more pedal travel on the next depress.

If however you are saying that the brake pedal feels as though it's traveling further all the time now, then you need to get the vehicle checked over asap, as its likely that a retaining pin or wedge etc has been dislodged perhaps skewing the caliper angle. This will lead to further pedal travel and also likely cause squealing.

Also.. As it sounds like there was a good impact here.. Have the tracking and suspension checked over too.

Answer (score 1):

No, the brake lines usually have a flexible part that has more movement than any of the suspension or steering parts. If you have damaged them somehow I would imagine that there is also damage to the suspension.